# Is this a good method of separation?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, separation-of-concerns

I am creating a web application that is tiered in the following way:

Controller > Service > Repository

I have a `ProductsController` which has the following action:

```
[ValidateModel]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateProduct([FromBody] CreateProductRequest request)
{
    var result = _productService.CreateProduct(_mapper.Map<ProductSM>(request));

    switch (result.StatusCode)
    {
        case HttpStatusCode.BadRequest:
             return NotFound(result);
    }

    return Ok(_mapper.Map<GetAllProductsResponse>(result.ToItemResponse().Data));
}
```

This then calls the `ProductService` to create a product like so:

```
public IResponse<ProductSM> CreateProduct(ProductSM productSM)
    {
        if (DoesProductNameExists(productSM.Name))
        {
            return new ErrorResponse<ProductSM>
            {
                Message = $"Product {productSM.Name} already exists.",
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
            };
        }

        _productRepository.Insert(_mapper.Map<Product>(productSM));
        _productRepository.SaveChangesAsync();

        return new ItemResponse<ProductSM>
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
        };
    }
```

You will notice the following:

1.) The `CreateProduct` in `ProductsController` accepts a `CreateProductRequest` which is then mapped to `ProductSM` (service model) then within the `ProductService` the `ProductSM` is then mapped to `Product` (entity).

Is this the correct way of doing this? If not, then why because I feel as if this is decoupling the layers and strictly following a separation of concern idea.

2.) In the `ProductService` I return an `IResponse` which can be an `ItemResponse` (for successful calls) or `ErrorResponse` (for errors) which is then handled in the controller as the controller action returns a different result depending on the status code.

Is the best way of handling business layered errors. As for simple validations based on the request I'd expect the controller to handle this hence the `[ValidateModel]` attribute which checks that the model is valid, once this passes every other validation will be business layer related so im wondering what is the best way of handling these errors from business layer.

If you see anything else wrong with how I've done things then please do mention!

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613514/is-this-a-good-method-of-separation "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Answer (score 1):

The `ProductService` is tightly coupled to http. You cant switch hosting without changing the `ProductService`.

I instead let a exception handler deal we this so the domain can be completely separated from the hosting

```
public class ExceptionHandlingMiddleware
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, IExceptionMapping> ExceptionMappings = new Dictionary<Type, IExceptionMapping>();

    public ExceptionHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        if (next == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Next is required");
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IEnumerable<IExceptionMapping> mappers, DefaultExceptionMapping defaultMapper)
    {
        var exception = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>().Error;
        var type = exception.GetType();
        if (!ExceptionMappings.ContainsKey(exception.GetType()))
            ExceptionMappings[type] = mappers.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ExceptionType.IsAssignableFrom(type)) ?? defaultMapper;

        var mapping = ExceptionMappings[type];

        context.Response.StatusCode = (int) mapping.Status;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(mapping.FormatMessage(exception));
    }
}

public interface IExceptionMapping
{
    Type ExceptionType { get; }
    HttpStatusCode Status { get; }
    string FormatMessage(Exception e);
}

public class NamedExceptionMapping<TException> : IExceptionMapping where TException : Exception
{
    public Type ExceptionType { get; } = typeof(TException);
    public HttpStatusCode Status { get; }

    private readonly string _caption;

    public NamedExceptionMapping(HttpStatusCode status, string caption)
    {
        _caption = caption;
        Status = status;
    }

    public string FormatMessage(Exception e)
    {
        return $"{_caption} {e.Message}";
    }
}

public class DefaultExceptionMapping : IExceptionMapping
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _env;
    public Type ExceptionType { get; } = typeof(Exception);
    public HttpStatusCode Status { get; } = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

    public DefaultExceptionMapping(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;
    }

    public string FormatMessage(Exception e)
    {
        if (_env.IsDevelopment()) return $"{e.Message}; stracktrace: {e.StackTrace}";
        return e.Message;
    }
}
```

Configured like

```
services        
    .AddTransient<DefaultExceptionMapping>()
    .AddSingleton<IExceptionMapping>(new NamedExceptionMapping<ArgumentException>(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Bad arguments"))
    .AddSingleton<IExceptionMapping>(new NamedExceptionMapping<UnauthorizedAccessException>(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Forbidden"))
    .AddSingleton<IExceptionMapping>(new NamedExceptionMapping<AuthenticationException>(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized"));
```

You could off course do it alot less complex than this, its essentially a exception type to http code mapper. In the domain you can now throw normal exceptions and they will be mapped to status codes

Also I would move the responsibility of calling `SaveChanges` out of the domain and let your framework handle it. Thats how I did it in my system, like

```
private async Task ExecuteCommand(Func<Command> commandFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, int? id =null)
{
    var ctx = serviceProvider.GetService<IBusinessContextController>();
    var repository = serviceProvider.GetService<ICommandRepository>();
    var queuedCommand = id.HasValue;
    Command cmd = null;

    try
    {
        cmd = commandFactory();
        ctx.ExecutionContext = new ExecutionContext {Id = id, Name = cmd.GetType().Name};

        await ExecuteCommandInternalAsync(cmd, serviceProvider);

        await ctx.StartTransactionAsync();

        if (queuedCommand)
            await repository.UpdateStateAsync(CommandState.Completed);

        await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
        await ctx.CommitTransactionAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.LogError(e, $"Error executing command {cmd?.GetType().FullName} ({id})");
        ctx.RollbackTransaction();
        if (queuedCommand)
        {
            await repository.UpdateStateAsync(CommandState.Error);
            await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        else
            throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like the idea of using exceptions, its inefficient and validation errors aren't exceptions. Your app should be dealing with these types of requests rather throwing exceptions because a request is wrong.

Comment: I use fluent validation ontop of this. So uncommon for bad argument exceptions to be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good design.  This is very similar how I did things in ASP.NET MVC and how I my team works in Ruby on Rails.  I like how the service model handles orchestration and checsk for errors, how the mapper takes care of converting objects, etc.

I do have some questions.  I'm curious why you have both a `Product` and a `ProductSM`?  Why two different models?  What are their responsibilities?

I"m also curious about the `[ValidateModel]` attribute?  Complex workflows will not have a single method of validation, but multiple depending on context.  For example, in our system, we have at least 6 different types of validation for one of our models depending on whether its status is moving to "Draft", "Pending", "Approved", etc.  See https://jeffreypalermo.com/2009/05/the-fallacy-of-the-always-valid-entity/

Comment: The reason why I have 2 different models one `Product` being an entity model whilst `ProductSM` is a service model is because this is how i feel things should be separated. I dont think my services should be handling the data models as the data models should be only used in the DAL

Comment: Not how I would do it, but that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good design, although it is probably not uncommon. Here are a few reasons:

1. `ProductsController` does nothing of consequence. It just calls the service, so it's just another layer to maintain without added logic. Or do you want to "decouple" from HTTP? Because YAGNI.
2. The `CreateProduct` it tightly coupled to the data in the product and what 'name' means. I'm curious how `DoesProductNameExists` is implemented, I guess it calls the repository again. So it basically knows things that it shouldn't, or to frame it differently: it will change when some underlying details change.
3. The repository has temporal details leaking. Like calling `SaveChangesAsync` after insert. That kind of stuff should not be the caller's responsibility, or it should offer some other safer ways to do it.
4. The whole thing is entirely technical, not based on business. Consequence of this is when changes occur (a new feature) it will likely not be localized, i.e. the application is not maintainable.

Comment: 1.) The `ProductsController` is a layer which should do the necessary calls. In this instance, the controller is responsible for first checking if the `ModelState` is valid by using the attribute `[ValidateModel]` after this then the controller should ask the `ProductService` to create a product. This is what I feel the controllers responsibilities should be.

Comment: 3.) I feel as if the service is the best place to call `SaveChanges` method because sometimes as part of a transaction you may work with multiple repositories. And then you want to persist the changes across multiple repositories in one transaction

Comment: I don't agree with 1 because the controller does have responsibilities: handling the web request and response. Just because it's simple doesn't meant it's not a responsibility. Additionally, you're ignoring that this is just one of many controllers. Even if there are some controllers that are mere passthroughs, there may be other controllers which have more responsibilities. If OP needs a controller/service layer for the latter, then they should uniformly apply that controller/service layer (which includes applying it to the passthrough controllers).

Comment: @flater The controller does not handle the request, the framework does that. There is nothing in there that is different from the service. Would you keep it anyway, even if it does nothing? That is just complicating a design for no real reason, I don't think that's a good thing.

Comment: @RobertBräutigam: OP is likely not showing you the most complex example of their architecture. You should account for the fact that _some_ controllers may have more responsibilities than others. It's better to uniformly implement an architecture than it is to use two different architectures at the same time depending on the complexity of a given controller. When a change adds the final straw to make it cross the border (becoming more complex or less complex), you'd suddenly have to move it from one architecture to the next.

Comment: Additionally, what if there's a webservice and a windows service that both consume the same BLL services? If you put that logic in the webservice's controller; then your windows service can't consume it. A separation is much better here because it leaves the business logic **reusable**. I do agree that one should be on the lookout for overengineering, but I don't agree that this is actually a case of overengineering.